# Can white tokens be used to pay for white mana in a convoke cost?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can white tokens be used to pay for white mana in a convoke cost?

I know that tokens with summoning sickness can tap for convoke, but I was wondering if these tokens are considered "white". For example, if I want to cast [Ephemeral Shields](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ephemeral%20Shields) and I have two untapped white soldier tokens, can I tap both tokens to cover the colorless and the white in the mana cost?

Comment: What do you mean by "pay for its island mana cost?" Nothing in your question involves blue cards (or tokens), and Islands produce mana, they aren't a type of mana.

Comment: I removed the unclear sentence about islands. I assumed that it was probably just a typo and you meant plains, in which case the remainder of the question already covers it. If it wasn't a typo and you need specific help with something involving islands, just ask a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use white tokens to pay for white mana costs with Convoke. The [rule for Convoke](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Convoke) says

> Convoke is a static ability that functions while the spell with convoke is on the stack. "Convoke" means "**For each colored mana in this spell’s total cost, you may tap *an untapped creature of that color* you control rather than pay that mana**. For each generic mana in this spell’s total cost, you may tap an untapped creature you control rather than pay that mana." The convoke ability isn’t an additional or alternative cost and applies only after the total cost of the spell with convoke is determined.

And [a relevant rule regarding tokens](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Permanent) says

> **110.5b** The spell or ability that creates a token may define the values of any number of characteristics for the token. This becomes the token's "text." **The characteristic values defined this way are functionally equivalent to the characteristic values that are printed on a card**; for example, they define the token's copiable values. A token doesn't have any characteristics not defined by the spell or ability that created it.

So, when a spell or ability creates a White Soldier creature token, it is functionally equivalent to a creature card that is White and a Soldier. This functional equivalence extends to paying for white convoke costs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a creature token on the battlefield is a creature.

---

"Creature" means "creature permanent".

> 109.2. If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn’t include the word “card,” “spell,” “source,” or “scheme,” it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.

"Permanent" means "card or token on the battlefield".

> 110.1. A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield. [...]

So "creature" refers to both creature cards on the battlefield and creature tokens on the battlefield.